# App crashes when text selected in uitextview

Tags: xcode, crash, uitextview

I'm coding what is supposed to be a pretty simple app, one aspect of which is a uitextview. The view loads and is srollable without any hassles, but if the user attempts to press and hold to select some text, the app crashes:

> 2012-07-30 23:07:01.547 SASB[36340:c07] +[_UIDictionaryWrapper _availableDictionaryAssets] returned failed - retrying. Error: Error Domain=ASError Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ASError error 4 - Unable to copy asset information)" UserInfo=0xaa64b90 {NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information}
>   SASB(36340,0xac2a7a28) malloc: *** error for object 0xaa611a0: double free
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   (lldb)

I have no idea why this is happening. I'm not too good at debugging at the best of times, but this just keeps throwing me back to the main.m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

Comment: If you go to the Breakpoint navigator tab in Xcode and set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions, it **should** cause the debugger to stop where the error is encountered rather than jumping into main.m.  It's not guaranteed to work but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried creating a symbolic breakpoint with symbol [NSException raise] but it's not being triggered when this error is thrown :(

Comment: I've just noticed that the App crashes when ever I select text in any object. Web View, Search Box... As soon as text is selected, CRASH :(

Answer (score 1):

O0ops!

It seems that this may be a bug in Xcode 4.5 beta. I'd completely forgotten that I was even using the beta. Guess I'll have to skip the IOS6 features for now :)

Comment: Interesting. I just noticed the same problem and am also using the beta. Disregard for now? It doesn't crash my app, I just noticed it in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are right Christopher.  I have an app I am testing against ios6 and I get the same console message.

In my case the app continues to run just fine and data is saved when editing is finished with the UITextView object just like it did with ios5.